# geometric representations in convex analysis

Tags: convex-analysis

Do you have any advices that help having geometric representations in convex analysis ? (for instance examples you always keep in mind when you are working, websites with simulations, graphs , ...)

I have found some difficulties when I am following proofs on textbooks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is too broad.  Some more context might help: what level of convex analysis are you dealing with?  Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$?  Banach spaces?

One general piece of advice: in many cases (though not all), the important features can be visualized in two dimensions.  If at all possible, try to picture the situation in two dimensions or in a two-dimensional slice of a larger space.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My setting is generally $\mathbb{R}^n$